# Is it possible to first move all the varibles to one side then square both sides?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say i have the equation $(x+3.75)^{0.5} = x$, could i first subtract x from both sides to $(x+3.75)^{0.5} - x= 0 $ and then square to $x+3.75 + (-x)^2 = 0$?

Comment: $(a+b)^{2} \neq a^{2}+b^{2}$.

Comment: It is true that $A=B\Leftrightarrow (A-B)^2=0$, but you cannot make mistakes of algebra when you compute $(A-B)^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your question to MathJax formatting. Also, you may provide more context to your question, for example, where did you see this kind of problem, what contest was this problem in, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the square root alone at one side of the equality before squaring both sides, otherwise you won't be able to solve it since $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Look that $(\sqrt{x + 3.75} - x)^2 =$ $x + 3.75 - 2x\sqrt{x + 3.75}+x^2$ so you don't get rid of the square root by doing that but see that $\sqrt{x+3.75} = x \implies x+3.75 = x^2 \implies x^2 - x - 3.75 = 0$ and now you solve for that second degree polynomial. Don't forget to check the solutions you get by just substituting x and checking that what is inside the square root is greater than 0.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot about that